# Java class file could not be launched on startup

Tags: macos, java, startup

I'm not sure what happened but now when I boot up my Mac I get this message that pops up every time:

"The Java class file "myClass.class" could not be launched.
Check the Console for possible error messages."

This class file is part of a larger program I'm developing.

I checked the console and found the message with sender `[0x0-0x1b01b].com.apple.JarLauncher` and the message says `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ...`.

I failed to find the Jar Launcher or anything Java related in `/Library/StartupItems` and `~/Library/StartupItems` but that's all I thought to do.

Any ideas on why I'm getting this message and what to do to get rid of it?

Comment: 1) `com.apple.JarLauncher` or the program you're developing may be started at login if they saved state: In the Finder press Cmd+Shift+G and type `~/Library/Saved Application State`. Now look for folders named `com.apple.JarLauncher` and after your program's identifier. Delete them. 2) Boot in safe mode (support.apple.com/kb/ht1564). If no message pops up look for `jarLauncher` and `myClass.class` entries in `/Library/LaunchAgents` and `~/Library/LaunchAgents`. 3) Unlikely, but check whether a login hook is defined: `defaults read com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook`. Try `sudo defaults ...` also.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it in System Preferences -> Users -> Login items.